# AzurStor in R: Why do readRDS and storage_load_rds not return the same output

Tags: r, serialization, azure-storage

I want to load a file from Azur cloud storage named "file_last_dates.rds". The original function used was readRDS, and I'm changing it to storage_load_rds. The latter function is not returning the same thing as readRDS.

This is the output that I want:

```r
> readRDS("/home/.../file_last_dates.rds")

$`st_rfe.mli.{year}_dek.sf.rds`
[1] "2022-12-31"

$`st_rfe.mli.{year}_day.sf.rds`
[1] "2022-12-31"
```

But this is the output that I'm getting:

```r
> storage_load_rds(cont,"file_last_dates.rds")

[[1]]
[[1]]$`st_rfe.mli.{year}_dek.sf.rds`
[1] "2022-12-31"

[[1]]$`st_rfe.mli.{year}_day.sf.rds`
[1] "2022-12-31"
```

How do I fix the second output so that it looks like the first output? Thanks.

Comment: `storage_load_rds(cont,"file_last_dates.rds")[[1]]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I fix the second output so that it looks like the first output

I agree with @r2evans comment , you can use the **`storage_load_rds(cont,"file_last_dates.rds")[[1]]`** to get the required format as same readRDS.

I tried with the below r code and it executed successfully.

**Code:**

```
library(AzureStor)

# Define Azure Blob Storage credentials
account_endpoint <- "https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net"
storage_account_key <- "your account key"
container_name <- "test"
bl_endp_key <- storage_endpoint(account_endpoint, key=storage_account_key)
cont <- storage_container(bl_endp_key, container_name)

# Load the RDS file from Azure Blob Storage
file_last_dates <- storage_load_rds(cont, "file_last_dates.rds")[[1]]

# Print the contents of the RDS file
print(file_last_dates)
```

**Output:**

```
$`st_rfe.mli.{year}_dek.sf.rds`
[1] "2022-12-31"

$`st_rfe.mli.{year}_day.sf.rds`
[1] "2022-12-31"
```

[image]